# What should we do with a XY problem question, where X can be easily answered?

Tags: discussion

I came over this question today [**128 bit integers support in GCC**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531531/128-bit-integers-support-in-gcc).

The OP asks for support of 128 bit integer representation support as the title says, but want's to use these 128 bit integers to represent an IPv6 address, which is certainly the wrong way to approach the problem.

There are already suitable structs available to represent IPv6 addresses, and these will work well with the corresponding socket types.

I've been voting to close this question using a custom reason, since I'm afraid other researchers might pick up this Q&A as an appropriate solution for that IPv6 requirement.

What do you think?

Comment: Just because the question is asking for `Y` doesn't mean you can't provide an answer for `X` or both

Comment: @psubsee2003 Good points in the dupe. But I didn't raise mod attention, but used a custom close reason.

Comment: Very true, but I am interpreting "flagging" in the broader sense here (to include any flag or related action, such as closing), so given  Robert's answer addresses your question and the questions are similar enough, it's a dup IMO.

Comment: @psubsee2003 In this particular case we fortunately found that X and Y were stated clearly enough in the OP, and thus simply can be solved by answering.

Comment: No need to downvote. I've been agreeing the dupe myself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the question is an entirely sensible, answerable, quality question, then simply answer it.  If you would like to provide additional information either at the end of an answer or in a comment that the answer to this question isn't the correct solution to another similar problem that you think might be the real problem, then you're more than welcome to do so.

That the question author might actually be better off asking a different question is not any reason to close the question that they did ask.

Comment: _"quality question"_ Actually I have problems with this point.

Comment: Well, I've been following your advice, retracted my close vote and answered the question. THX (still have my doubts about the quality, but who cares ;-P ...)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If the question isn't a quality question then address that point.  The fact that the OP doesn't have a problem that the question solved wouldn't affect how you handle any other problems with the question, such as its scope, clarity, on-topicness, etc.  The point is simply that it's entirely possible to ask a great question about a problem you don't have.  You having a different problem than what the question asks doesn't inherently *make* the question low quality.  Of course, the fact that you have a different problem doesn't mean it can't also have other problems.

Comment: The
 quality problems with the post were/are twofold: that the title only mentioned the X problem (128-bit ints in GCC), potentially leading to a little sand trap for a searcher (although that problem is satisfactorily answered in this case), and that the information sought (when did GCC start supporting X, and on which architectures) is list-y.  I've edited the title, but there's nothing to be done about the other. Since GCC is unlikely to _retroactively_ remove support, however, this should be able to fly (even more so since the Y problem is not time-dependent). @πάνταῥεῖ