# Should this specific hot question about high level approaches to improve performances be closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, hot-questions

[This hot question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32907258/4174897) gathered more than a thousand views and some upvotes in a fairly short time.

It can be summed up in the following way:

> I am doing mathy stuff then compiling it to C++:
>
> ```
> mathy stuff code in C++
> ```
>
> It is not very good performance-wise.
> **What approach should I take to optimize this implementation?**

The emphasised part is quoted from the actual question.

It seemed to me that this question was either a tool request or too broad. It got [closed as too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32907258/revisions), but it has now been reopened.

Is this question off-topic?
Should it be sent to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)?

Comment: Yes, it is most definitely off-topic.

Comment: ... aaand it's closed as Too Broad again.

Comment: Someone posts something that users enjoy reading about, both the problem and possible approaches.  Rule lawyer appears, complaining that it's off topic in meta.  Valid interesting question gets closed, and probably deleted in a few weeks time.  Thanks rule lawyers!

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica Note that you do have the re-open vote privilege.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica just because it is something that people enjoy reading about does not mean that it is on-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: It's now been re-opened for the third time...

Answer (score 55):

**[Edit it.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32907258/revisions)** The guy's trying to learn how to optimize math, and as usual assumes there's some tool out there (bullet-shaped, made of magic and silver) that will solve the problem for him. But what he really wants is guidance, knowledge born of experience... So make the question reflect his true desires.

#### See also: [What exactly is a recommendation question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question)

### Addressing concerns raised in the comments

> Isn't the question still too broad and also opinion-based?

It's really not very broad. Oh, it's not *trivial*, but given the constraints of the problem there are relatively few practical solutions, and so far only one purely speculative answer has been posted (and isn't doing very well).

I guess it's somewhat opinion-based, but no more than usual - there are multiple approaches. The author didn't ask for everyone's favorite optimization techniques, he presented a specific class of problems that he needs to optimize.

> It's a *list question*

The term "list question" is ill-defined; [it started out as shorthand](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124450/what-is-the-definition-of-a-list-question/124489#124489) for a problematic sort of question now so reviled no one bothers to even defend it anymore. If you're curious, read [Real Questions Have Answers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). None of that applies to *this* question.

> It needs benchmarks to be answerable

This isn't that type of problem. Oh, I'm sure the author will use some sort of benchmarking (and probably already has) to evaluate his progress, and a good profiler *might* aid him in identifying steps that are unusually costly... But in my experience, this sort of problem is rather difficult to profile accurately without careful preparation and plenty of trial and error - which may be part of an answer, but isn't a good reason to close the question.

> What about [Computational Science Stack Exchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)?

Not a bad choice if that's where the author is coming from - indeed, there are several similar questions there already. That said, this is as much a problem for programmers tasked with implementing the work of scientists or engineers, and I'll wager programmers experienced with this work are more likely to hang out here on Stack Overflow. Heck, this was *my* job for a few years. Not all programmers spend their days making web pages.

This strikes me as a well-asked, specific, **programming question**. I see no reason to close it.

Comment: Isn't **"What approach should I take to optimize this implementation?"** still too broad and opinion-based?

Comment: I guess I wasn't the only one who wants the question to stay on SO. (Even if the wording cries of Code Review migration.)

Comment: Seems pretty damn specialized to me, @Kyll - but then, it's Saturday and I'm still on my first pot of coffee. If you can convey the intent more clearly, contribute your own edit! I just closed two questions where the code wasn't formatted and the author forgot to bother constructing an actual problem statement; if you find someone who's managed to identify the problem and is hung up on finding wording that'll appease the pedants, take 30 seconds and throw 'em a bone...

Comment: @Kyll maybe something like this *It currently runs 1000 calculations per second but my requirement is to run this at least at 2000 c/ps. How would I reach that goal*

Comment: @rene If that question features benchmarks and profiles and a clear objective then yes, it would be on-topic. Right now it's little more than a code dump, a "does not work very well" sentence and the question is "what do I do now?" which is too broad and opinion-based.

Comment: Again, I don't think you're quite reading the question as the author intended it, @Kyll - optimizing that particular example isn't gonna get him very far, since he's apparently **generating** similar bits of code left and right based on engineering equations. He needs to learn how to optimize code so-generated in a way that can be applied to his workflow, not hand-tweak the specific example.

Comment: So that would mean the question is in fact how to tell Maple to generate the best C++ performance-wise? This was indeed not at all what I read and may still be too broad and lacking benchmarks.

Comment: @Kyll Here is how I read that Q&A: Q: "Maple is generating some obviously horrible C++ for me, such as the code in this snippet. Is there any trick to make the generated code better?" A: "There is no trick, but you can quite easily rewrite it into something more manageable." It is neither too broad, nor a recommendation question, nor (necessarily) a code review question, and benchmarks aren't essential either. It is a [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/242059) of sorts, but that [does not justify closure](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275182/2751851).

Comment: @Mystical I'm not sure that the question would be 100% on-topic on Code Review, since the code is auto-generated (CR requires that the code be written by the author of the question) and the request isn't to improve this code itself, but rather for a magical solution to fix all numerically intensive code of this sort. It could be _made_ into a Code Review question, but migrating and transforming questions risks offending the author.

Comment: Perhaps [scicomp.se] would be a better migration target than Code Review, if the question were deemed off-topic for Stack Overflow and worthy enough to migrate.

Comment: "I guess it's somewhat opinion-based, but no more than usual - there are multiple approaches." -- A key observation. There being multiple approaches does not make a question too broad or opinion based.

Comment: @Kyll: By your original comment, literally any question with more than one answer would be opinion-based.

Comment: It's obviously a list question.

Comment: It's obviously not, @Lightness. But if you wanna argue that point, post an answer and present your rationale.

Comment: I have very little interest in doing so, but I'm providing a critique on _this_ answer.

Comment: You're not even doing that; I suspect you're just trolling. But on the off-chance someone takes you seriously, I've edited to respond to you anyway.

Comment: "Not all programmers spend their days making web pages" -- thank you

Comment: From "What exactly is a recommendation question": ""Recommendation question" is shorthand for "you didn't describe a problem, you just asked for a list of things."" Or in this case, 1 thing. "Ask how, not what" - this question explicitly asks "what". The asker seems to have put little to no effort into trying to solve the problem themself. Optimising complicated mathematical expressions is not exactly an uncommon need in computing circles, and I'd expect Google could point you in the right direction. My opinion: Too Broad. Close it.

Comment: @IanKemp "this question explicitly asks 'what'" -- Except that this "what" can be very easily converted into a "how", unless you only accept radically literal interpretations.

Comment: @IanKemp wouldn't it be awesome if Google pointed you to the correct answer on SO? There shouldn't be a problem with duplicating knowledge that was available elsewhere.

Answer (score 32):

Full disclosure: I do have an answer on this question

I am giving my viewpoint based on the fact that I am an active contributor to [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).  When working with large calculations like what was presented in the question there are a few steps to take that are general to large calculations.  As detailed by [David Hammen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/774499/david-hammen) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32914124/4342498) they are to:

- pre-calculate repeated calculations
- switching to a more optimized function when approporiate
- refactoring the equation

This question and the answers that were provided are useful for other people looking to do complicated calculations as efficiently as possible.  They can see how you would approach taking a large ugly unwieldy equation and turn it into something that not only looks good but is more efficient.

I do not feel it should be closed but instead used as a target for people with these same issues.

Comment: Agree, I think questions about programming techniques for numerical and scientific computing should be on-topic.

Comment: Full disclosure: Like Nathan Oliver, I too have an answer to this question. This is not just a good question, it's one of the better ones at this site as of late. It is about an important part of computer programming, important enough that a beta site (scicomp) has been spawned just to cover this topic. The question has brought a lot of traffic to the site, it has generated a good deal of discussion, and it has generated a number of good answers that have addressed the question from different points of view. What more could the site want?

Comment: @DavidHammen To be only slightly tongue-in-cheek, more jQuery, probably.

Answer (score 4):

- If it's about that specific code snippet, then it's asking for code review ("look at this and maybe improve it"), though I don't know if Code Review would actually take it.
- If it's just asking "How do I optimize math in general?", it's too broad.  A proper answer would explain how to use a profiler to see what (parts of) expressions are expensive, what optimizations compilers can already do for you (and how to verify they're being performed), and what manual code changes are likely to help (and there are many possibilities).  It's a reasonable question, but I don't think Stack Overflow is the right place to answer it.
- If it's asking "How can I convince Maple to generate better code, or clean up after it?", it might be on-topic -- a Maple expert might know how what kinds of input Maple handles well or of a tool designed to clean up its output.  (This isn't how I interpreted this question, but then, I've never used Maple so I naturally didn't think of it.)

Comment: Or the fourth: "How can I write a better snippet than what Maple has generated?"