# Prohibiting to ask about a problem rather than specific solution leads to XY problems and doesn't really work

Tags: discussion, scope

Recently, I've been bumping into a noticeable number of [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) questions (see also [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

The specific one that incited me to write this is [How to continue a frame execution from last attempted instruction after handling an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425356/how-to-continue-a-frame-execution-from-last-attempted-instruction-after-handling).

Let's see what happens there:

- The OP asks about Y (how to "resume" after exception)
- others are dazzled and wonder why they need it, say this isn't really possible etc
- the OP eventually tells X (recover from an error down the stack)
- the accepted and most upvoted answer actually *answers that question* instead of the original one

The first impulse I had was to reformulate/advise to reformulate the question to X. *But then, I realized that in that case, it would be closed as too broad/opinion-based!*

So,

- a user cannot ask about his actual problem in fear of the question being closed
- asking about a solution instead

  - produces an XY problem (which, as per the above link, wastes resources)
  - yields answers that do not correspond to the question
  - but actually address the original problem

Consequently,

- this is a working way to trick the community into answering a question it otherwise wouldn't - in fact, a necessary trick to get around the (draconian) scope limit
- the scope limit thus doesn't actually work as the community invariably sees such questions as valid

Thus, the question is:

- Which way to go?

  - allow users to actually ask about problems they have and aren't quite sure how to solve?

    - on some conditions, perhaps
  - further limit the scope by prohibiting to address anything other than what was originally asked?

    - note that programming is by its nature R&D work - i.e. in vast majority of cases, a person doesn't know how to solve a problem beforehand
  - leave it as is which means endorse/condone necessary tricks like this?

Comment: *This is a working way to trick the community into answering a question it otherwise wouldn't.* You're more paranoid than I am. No small feat.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I didn't imply this is intended (Hanlon's razor)! I said _it effectively works like this._ My belief is the vast majority aren't actually realizing they do this.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi And, I didn't ask "what to do for a specific question", I assert this probably shows the current interpretation of scope is inadequate and am asking if it is and how it shall be fixed if it should. But, if you're positive the question has more chances this way... (yes, the same kind of trick)

Comment: Yup, I understand your meta-question is not tied to a specific question. Hopefully that's still clear after my title edit.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi the problem is, your edit shifted the focus greatly: from "is X really off-topic?" to "it's off-topic, no question about that, but how to handle a Q&A?" That's the reason for my "more chances this way" notice.

Comment: No problem, feel free to revert my edit. I actually changed your title because I had a hard time understanding it, but maybe it was just me :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi a hard-to-understand title is no good anyway, and the body and this discussion is still here for all to see. Okay, let's just wait for feedback and see which topic it's on.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that these questions are numerous. "My drop-down box isn't populated" boils down to: "how do I get data from the database?". And yes, the latter would go down as "too broad" in no time.

But if this isn't intended behavior (as you say in a comment) there's not much we can do. We can't educate people to ask about X (supposing we'd go that way), if they don't realize it's even there. If the OP doesn't realize that the problem is in the X part, they are helped by getting that pointed out. Making them aware of the underlying problem could be an answer in itself, although most of the times questions like this tend to turn into [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/168269).

> Which way to go?

As always, tell people to ask pointed questions. If there really are some who deliberately try to skirt around close reasons by wrapping their general question into something more specific, so be it. They probably don't help themselves because the question is more obscure than it needs to be and they're likely to get answers they're not waiting for.

From my experience, the vast majority of XY questions are questions from users that aren't even aware of the X. Sometimes they're downright lazy, sometimes they lack analyzing skills, sometimes they're too focused and forget to step back. Whatever the reason, it may still be a good question that [deserves an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275183/861716). If it isn't, closing is the appropriate action.

Comment: The XY problem itself is not the problem. The problem is I can't fix it - whether by educating users or otherwise.

Comment: Educating users is a hopeless enterprise anyway. I think the main point I try to make is that an XY question, deliberate or not, is just a normal question and should be judged on its merits just as any other question. The greatest challenge is probably to avoid getting sucked into the moving target trap they're likely to open (chameleon question). But that's an answerer's responsibility.