# What should be done, when a question has implications, which lead to a correct, but misleading answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, low-quality-posts, asking-questions

## General problem

Questions can implicate the usage of a tool, which is capable to solve the given problem, however far from adequate for it, because the solution will be too obscure, unstable or insecure.

## Example

[How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed)

The problem with the question, that it implicates the usage of `sed`, which is capable, but not adequate tool for this task, because it is line-based.

### Adequate and useful solution

Replacing newlines in the Unix shell is a very simple task.

```
tr '\n' ' ' < file
```

Code copied from the 2nd answer.

### Correct, accepted but misleading answer

However if someone uses `sed`

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' file
```

Code copied from first, accepted answer, which according to the comments won't work on Mac OS X, and the cross-platform solution is:

```
sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/ /g' file
```

I mean we are replacing newlines with spaces... even if someone is not an Unix user, but has a little experience, will see the problem. However newbies could be misled or even worse scared off.

## Question

So we have technically correct and still misleading accepted and first positioned answer and a good second and not accepted one, what are our choices?

Comment: Fixing a bad answer is incredibly simple, post a better one.

Comment: @HansPassant someone already posted a better one, which also has a higher score but still not the first to show up and not the accepted one. However thank you I clarified this in my question.

Comment: You'll get used to it.

Comment: Your only choice is to vote as you see fit. If you are bothered about the accepted answer being pinned, see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top). Not VtCing this one as dupe because of how your question is phrased, but I do think it is actually what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, @yivi your link addresses most of my dilemas, except one. Should I downvote a technically correct, but otherwise harmful answer?

Comment: That's up to you. If you feel the bad outweights the good in that answer, you may feel that the answer is not useful or well researched, and vote accordingly. But in the end it's your choice.

Comment: Well, note that in this case OP "intentionally" make "*interesting*" questions by [doing unusual things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed#comment1078907_1252010).

Comment: The real problem is that [the "real" question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826752/using-tr-to-replace-newline-with-space/25826920) is not interesting enough to ask or otherwise not as popular, therefore the other one comes up before in [results of search engines](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash%20replace%20newline%20by%20space%20in%20file).

Comment: The only real "problem" with that answer is that, it does not say that the method used is not the correct one for "normal user", i.e., if they use Bash. Just add a "**NOTE**: If you are not forced to use `sed`, you can just use `tr` instead. See [this answer](https://example.com)", then it's perfect.

Comment: @user202729 thank you, editing the accepted answer seems to be a good response, I did that. Now it is waiting for peer-review. Do you want to write an answer from your comments?

Comment: I didn't intend to mean "edit the answer", I meant "tell the poster to edit their own answer" instead. Which doesn't work in this case, because the poster is not active. Anyway, now the answer is edited, it looks good.

Comment: @user202729 sorry I misinterpreted, I will check the user activity next time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should we do with a XY problem question, where X can be easily answered?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275182/what-should-we-do-with-a-xy-problem-question-where-x-can-be-easily-answered)

Comment: Also related: [A car with square wheels](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254341/a-car-with-square-wheels).

Comment: so this applies to `99%` of every [tag:regex] question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some simple and straightforward ways of dealing with this sort of issue:

1. If you think the question should be slightly different, ask a clarifying question in a comment. Hopefully the user sees this and responds to it.
2. If you think an answer deserves a caveat, leave an appropriate, polite comment on the answer.
3. If you think you have a better answer, leave that as an answer.

The process on stack overflow is highly democratic. We put information out here for public consumption, and the information put out should be as complete as possible. These actions will help ensure that.  We do not try to censor answers based on incompleteness or incorrectness. That's what voting does- and ultimately, it is up to the original asker to pick the answer that they feel best satisfies the intent of their question.

Comment: Everything what you wrote is right, but no completely answer my question.  However please note that @user202729 advised me in the comments to edit the accepted answer to point the other "better" one, which worked wonderfully and that "better" in this case is ambiguous (technically vs practically correct). Please include these in your answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: I do not recommend adding content to accepted answers. That is generally considered to be harmful, though there are specific instances when it might be appropriate.

Comment: I suspect this was a specific instance... considering everything I accept your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I disagree. The text you added, "As you can see using sed for this otherwise simple problem is problematic. If you search for a more simple and adequate solution please check this answer." is a great example of an invalid edit. It should have been left as a comment. And indeed, many, many users commented as such, so this is also redundant. The second answer is just as easily reachable as the first. Speaking for myself, I would prefer to have you put energy into working on problems which are actually problems :)